# 3 button choice

Tags: iphone, ios6, uibutton

In my application i have 3 buttons, i want to diable the remain 2 when any 1 button selected,i tried with following logic,here my code i used to execute it not working properly,

```
 -(void)checkboxSelected13:(id)sender
 {
       UIButton *btn = (UIButton *) sender;
       if([btn isSelected])
       {
            [bt27 setSelected:YES];
            [bt28 setSelected:NO];
            [bt29 setSelected:NO];
       }
       else if ([btn isSelected]) {
            [bt27 setSelected:NO];
            [bt28 setSelected:YES];
            [bt29 setSelected:NO];
       }
       else
       {
            [bt27 setSelected:NO];
            [bt28 setSelected:NO];
            [bt29 setSelected:YES];
       }
}
```

What is wrong with my code? Please help

Comment: you probably want a UISegmentedControl, or a radio group

Comment: What's wrong is that your buttons and methods have names that are very hard to understand.

Answer (score 3):

You are checking the same condition "if([btn isSelected])" in both if-else part. That may cause confusion. And your code not working properly.

And your code is looking too long and like complex:

You can go with straight-forward implementation:

Give your button the tag property like button1=1, button2=2 and button3=3

Now check with below code:

```
-(IBAction)checkboxSelected:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *) sender;

    switch (btn.tag) {
    case 1:
        [btn1 setSelected:YES];
        [btn2 setSelected:NO];
        [btn3 setSelected:NO];
        break;
    case 2:
        [btn1 setSelected:NO];
        [btn2 setSelected:YES];
        [btn3 setSelected:NO];
        break;
    case 3:
        [btn1 setSelected:NO];
        [btn2 setSelected:NO];
        [btn3 setSelected:YES];
        break;
    default:
        [btn1 setSelected:NO];
        [btn2 setSelected:NO];
        [btn3 setSelected:NO];
        break;
    }
}
```

Hope, this will be helpful to you.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You should do like this and put different image as background image for selected state of button in xib file so that it can be differentiated easily

```
-(void)checkboxSelected13:(id)sender
 {

UIButton *btn = (UIButton *) sender;

if((btn == bt27) && ![btn isSelected])
{
    [bt27 setSelected:YES];
    [bt28 setSelected:NO];
    [bt29 setSelected:NO];
}
else if ((btn == bt28) && ![btn isSelected]) {
    [bt27 setSelected:NO];
    [bt28 setSelected:YES];
    [bt29 setSelected:NO];
}
else if ((btn == bt29) && ![btn isSelected])
{
    [bt27 setSelected:NO];
    [bt28 setSelected:NO];
    [bt29 setSelected:YES];

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign tab to your buttons. And then check :

```
-(void)checkboxSelected13:(id)sender
 {
      UIButton *btn = (UIButton *) sender;
      if(btn.tag == tagAssignedToButton27)
      {
           [bt27 setSelected:YES];
           [bt28 setSelected:NO];
           [bt29 setSelected:NO];
      }
      else if(btn.tag == tagAssignedToButton28)
      {
           [bt27 setSelected:NO];
           [bt28 setSelected:YES];
           [bt29 setSelected:NO];
      }
      else if(btn.tag == tagAssignedToButton29)
      {
           [bt27 setSelected:NO];
           [bt28 setSelected:NO];
           [bt29 setSelected:YES];
      }
}
```

More optimized way of doing this is use switch case inside your function `checkboxSelected13`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if([bt27 isSelected]) {
    [bt27 setSelected:YES];
    [bt28 setSelected:NO];
    [bt29 setSelected:NO];
} else if ([bt28 isSelected]) {
    [bt27 setSelected:NO];
    [bt28 setSelected:YES];
    [bt29 setSelected:NO];
} else if ([bt29 isSelected]) {
    [bt27 setSelected:NO];
    [bt28 setSelected:NO];
    [bt29 setSelected:YES];
} else {
    [bt27 setSelected:NO];
    [bt28 setSelected:NO];
    [bt29 setSelected:NO];
}
```

Logically, this is what you want. It's unclear how btn and btXY relate.

Answer (score 0):

```
if([btn isSelected]
   )
{
    [bt27 setSelected:YES];
    [bt28 setSelected:NO];
    [bt29 setSelected:NO];
}
else if ([btn isSelected]) {
    [bt27 setSelected:NO];
    [bt28 setSelected:YES];
    [bt29 setSelected:NO];
}
...
```

You are checking the same condition [btn isSelected] in both if and else if, change one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the main problem here is the logic and the code repetition. Although another type of control would be best for what you're after (something like a `UISegmentedControl` for example), you could try to solve the same problem with a more abstract idea, something like this perhaps (note here that all buttons trigger the same method now):

```
- (IBAction)checkboxSelected:(id)sender
{
    // Deselect any button that is already selected
    // of course a better approach would be to keep
    // an array with the buttons and just iterate through
    [bt27 setSelected:NO];
    [bt28 setSelected:NO];
    [bt29 setSelected:NO];

    // Select the button that triggered the action
    [(UIButton *)sender setSelected:YES];
}
```